# Unable to ping 10.8.0.1 once client is connected Linux base OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

Am I correct in thinking I should be able to ping 10.8.0.1 from the client?

The client connects to the server fine however am unable to ping the server using the 10.8.0.0 subnet.

I did a traceroute on it, it goes onto the Internet via my modem

```
 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.4.1
 2     1 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  SkyRouter.Home [192.168.0.1]
 3
```

SkyRouter is the combined router and modem sky gave me. Why?

Is it because my router doesn't know how to treat it so it assumes it's on the net.

Network structure:

```
Internet (sky router)  -----> (DMZ static IP) ---> WAN port Cisco RV 220W
```

The Cisco serves 5 different IP ranges for my 5 VLANs including Wi-Fi.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. By client I mean the PC am connecting to the VPN from. Its on a different vlan but its still connected to the Cisco. It does connect but I can't ping the server itself.  As demonstrated by the trace route it goes onto the internet why

Comment: I don't think its a firewall issue since I have it open to any port any source/destination combination

Comment: You need to show what IPs / networks you're using locally, what IPs / networks openvpn is giving you, what your routing table is before and after the openvpn connection is established.